# jQuery.noConflict() and Sharepoint 2010 WebParts

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I've made two webparts for Sharepoin 2010 with jQuery plugins `fancybox` (slider) and `cycle` (slider). I need to locate both webparts on one page. But it doesn't work. I tried to use `jQuery.noConflict()` to fix it:

For fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $jq("a[rel=group]").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

For cycle:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    function runSlider() {
        $jq('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade'
        });
   };   
</script> 

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    complete: function (xData, status) {
        var div = document.getElementById("slideshowdiv");
        jQuery(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
            var elem = document.createElement("img");
            elem.setAttribute("src", $(this).attr("ows_SliderContent").replace(',', ""));
            elem.setAttribute("height", "200");
            elem.setAttribute("width", "200");
            elem.setAttribute("alt", "test");
            elem.onload = runSlider;
            div.insertBefore(elem, div.firstChild);
        });
    }
 });
```

This code is in .ascx files of Visual WebParts.

Can you tell me, what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: did you ever call `runSlider`?

Comment: yes, of course, function 'runSlider' is used in ajax handler. I've updated code in question.

Comment: Can you let us know what the actual error is? Also why is the jquery.ajax outside the </script> tag?